# What are the issues by disabling the "DELETE" and "PUT" method from webserver server?

Tags: security, zend-framework, intrusion-detection

We have installed "Intruder Detection System" (IDS) to our web sever. According to it's recent report it recommend us to disable "DELETE" and "PUT" method from our webserver server.

I understand what these two methods can help to a Web attacker but I want to know by disabling these two methods will this harm my web Application (my web application is based on Zend Framework)? if So, do you know what kind of functionality will be disabled?

Comment: DELETE and PUT are generally used with REST or WebDav-style services. Disabling them will not affect *normal* GET or POST requests.

Comment: Thanks for this, and could you please give explanation links about  REST and WebDav-style services?